# Problem displaying error message after checking duplicates

Tags: php, html, sql

At the moment I'm new to php and trying to make a website. The problem I encountered is rather simple but I can't find a solution. When a user creates a new group, there needs to be a check if the name of the group already exists. If the name already exists, the user needs to see a message above the form "name already in use".

I tried a couple of things, in the code below is my latest try. This one made the most sense to me but I get a white screen (empty body) when i press the create group button.

```php
<?php
    if (array_key_exists('groupname', $_POST)) {
        if (checkDuplicateGroupName($_POST['groupname'])){
         //displaying the "error message" 
            echo '<div id="logreg-forms">
            <form class="form-signin" method="post">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal" style="text-align: center"> Create group</h1>
            <h2 class="h2 mb-3 font-weight-normal"> </h2>
            <input type="text" name="groupname" id="groupname" class="form-control" placeholder="Group Name" autofocus=""
                   required>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="60" type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"></textarea>

            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Create </button>
            <hr>

            <a href="http://stansft379.379.axc.nl/groups.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" > <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Cancel </a>

        </form>';
        } else{
            addgroup($_POST['groupname'], $_POST['description']); //tested and works
        }
    } else{
     // This one works when you go to the page, but after you press the submit buttons the body becomes empty. 
        echo '<div id="logreg-forms">
        <form class="form-signin" method="post">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal" style="text-align: center"> Create group</h1>

            <input type="text" name="groupname" id="groupname" class="form-control" placeholder="Group Name" autofocus=""
                   required>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="60" type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"></textarea>

            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Create </button>
            <hr>

            <a href="http://stansft379.379.axc.nl/groups.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" > <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Cancel </a>

        </form>';
    }
    ?>
```

And my checkDuplicateGroupName is:

```php
function checkDuplicateGroupName($groupname)
{
    $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DATABASE_USER = '--------';
    $DATABASE_PASS = '----------';
    $DATABASE_NAME = '---------'; //censored for obvious reasons

    $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT name FROM eventgroup");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $groupNameRow = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    foreach ($groupNameRow as $key => $value) {
        if (strcasecmp($value, $groupname) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Am I doing this correctly but what am I doing wrong. Also tips in general are welcome since I'm new to php.

Comment: if you got a white screen it likely means one of 2 things: 1) PHP crashed, but error reporting is not switched (in which case switch on either error reporting or error logging, and check the output), or 2) you posted back to a PHP script which then doesn't echo any output back to the browser.

Comment: Your function has several problems. First, it only checks the first row of the results. Second, `$value` is an array of all the columns in the row, you need `$value['name']`.

Comment: Why not use `WHERE name = ?` in the query instead of looping over all the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong. But there's no need for a loop, just query the database for the given name.

```
function checkDuplicateGroupName($groupname)
{
    $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DATABASE_USER = '--------';
    $DATABASE_PASS = '----------';
    $DATABASE_NAME = '---------'; //censored for obvious reasons

    $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM eventgroup WHERE name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $groupname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think about this one, thanks for your help.